# Need help understanding this particular regular expression [^.]

Tags: regex

```
[^.]+\.(txt|html)
```

I am learning regex, and am trying to parse this.

[^.] The ^ means "not", and the dot is a wildcard that means any character, so this means find a match with "not any character"?  I still don't understand this.  Can anyone explain?

The plus is a Kleene Plus which means "1 or more".  So now it's "one or more" "not any character".

I get `\.`, it means a period.

(txt|html) means match with a txt file or html file.  I think I understand everything after the plus sign.  What I don't understand is why it doesn't look something the DOS equivalent where I can just do this: *.txt or *.(txt|html) where * means everything that ends in the file extension .txt or .html?

Is [^.] the equivalent of * in DOS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The dot (`.`) has no special meaning when it's inside a character class, and doesn't require to be escaped.

`[^.]` means "*any character that is not a literal `.` character*". `[^.]+` matches one or more occurrences of any character that is *not* a dot.

From [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html):

> In most regex flavors, the only special characters or meta-characters inside a character class are the closing bracket (`]`), the backslash (`\`), the caret (`^`), and the hyphen (`-`). The usual meta-characters are normal characters inside a character class, and do not need to be escaped by a backslash. Your regex will work fine if you escape the regular metacharacters inside a character class, but doing so significantly reduces readability.

Answer (score 0):

`.` is not special inside `[]` character class. `[^.]+` means one or more occurrences (`+`) of any character which is not a dot.

If you do `*.txt` it would not be valid regex as `*` would not get a character to repeat (zero or more times).